# Comparing Strings in an Array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, compare

I have an array that stores a string at each index. I am trying to compare a users input to the array, to find the index the string is located. I can confirm that the user string and the array string is infact the same, but it is not giving me a true result. I have included a sample output as well. But if i enter "noaa 16" it cycles through the array, but misses the index.

```
    import ephem
    import datetime
    requestedSat = raw_input("Please enter the satellite you want to track")
    requestedSat = requestedSat.upper() #format the users input to fit the file constraints.
    tleFile = open("t")
    i = 0
    array = [None] * 100 #need to create a link list of sorts to account for larger files. If a file as more than 100 lines we will have an index error
    for line in tleFile: #read thew the file, counting how many lines there are, as well as adding each line to an array index.
        array[i] = line.translate(None,"[+-]") #removing special characters form the array. I dont know if they are important yet.
        i+=1

    j=0
    found = False

    for x in xrange(0,i/3):
        print requestedSat
        print "array = " + array[j]
        if requestedSat == array[j]:
            print "found it"

        else:
            j+=3
```

Here is the output. As you can see, the user typed NOAA 16, and the string value is stored in the array. How can i get it to compare the strings accurately

```
NOOA 16
array = NOAA 14              

NOOA 16
array = NOAA 15 B             

NOOA 16
array = NOAA 16              

NOOA 16
array = NOAA 17
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read lines using `for line in tleFile:`, each `line` will contain the terminating `\n` character at the end. That's just how the file object generator works. So your strings are, in fact, not identical, because `array[j]` has an extra line break at the end. You're in effect checking whether `'NOOA 16' == 'NOOA 16\n'`, which returns `False`.

You could solve this by stripping the compared strings of any leading and trailing whitespace characters:

```
if requestedSat.strip() == array[j].strip():
```

Comment: Ok i added  array[i] = line.translate(None,"[+-]").replace('\n', "").replace(" ", "")  but it made no difference :(

Comment: Why not try my suggested solution instead? Use `strip()` to make sure you don't miss any whitespace.

Comment: I thought the above code would remove the line breaks at the end. I used it when setting a string to the array index. I am maybe a little unclear? EDIT: "I didnt see that you edited your answer lol"

Comment: Well, it did, but `replace(" ", "")` replaced *all* spaces as well, not just the leading and trailing ones. So `NOAA 16` became `NOAA16`. No good! Just use the built-in `strip()`, it's concise, tried and tested, and that's what it's there for.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I am able to print out the lat long of the satellite now :)